# Java: Reset Singleton Object

Tags: java

I have created a dashboard that is Singleton. But I want to refresh(reload the default values) it every time a button is clicked. What could be best possible way to achieve this?

Code for the class:

```
public class UserDashboard extends Composite{            
private static UserDashboard userDash= new UserDashboard();  


private UserDashboard(){    

    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));


}


public static UserDashboard getDashInstance(){

    return userDash;

}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by refresh?

Comment: @DarshanLila  reload the default content.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a method which **refreshes** the singleton instance without recreating it.
You can put any meaning into **refreshes** (whatever appropriate).

Comment: then i need to explicitly set all the values to the default? there are lot many classes running on top of this class. Can't go on setting their values to default.

Comment: @Forkmohit "then i need to explicitly set all the values to the default" >>> What do you suggest instead?

Comment: posted this question for suggestions only.